# ms access queries build precentage calculation

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a standard MS access form, with multi value select fields , they are on the value list and NOT a table. I need to build a query involving one of the fields called Intake status . it has 4 values. I created the query to total all the values in the field individually. I want to know if I can calculate the individual values with the  overall all total and receive a percentage.

```
SELECT [DELAWARE MAIN TABLE].[Intake Status].Value, 
  Count([DELAWARE MAIN TABLE].[intake status]) AS [number of intakes]
FROM [DELAWARE MAIN TABLE]
GROUP BY [DELAWARE MAIN TABLE].[Intake Status].Value;

CONTRACT    301
LOI 135
ROSTER ONLY 6
    442
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Calculated Fields in a Query

https://www.599cd.com/tips/access/calculated-query-fields/

Video: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ISE1CVo53C4&list=PL786DE4C6D5244B47&index=31